# String to React DOM object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react js 15.4.2. I have html data stored as string like `"<p>Hello..</p>"`. I can not append them to the DOM.

```
...
componentDidMount(){
  let obj = dataFromDB.map((data)=>{
               return(
                  <div>
                    {data.strHtml}
                  </div>
               ) 
            }) 
   this.setState({storedObj: obj})
}

render(){
    return(
      <div>
          {this.state.storedObj}
      </div>
    )
}
...
```

Do you have any suggestions to append the html objects to the DOM properly ?

Answer (score 6):

you could also look into [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) module for parsing html before rendering to the DOM it's pretty easy to use.

```
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';    

class Example extends React.Component {

render() {
   return (
     <div>
       {Parser(this.state.dataStored)}
     </div>
   )
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use this code -

```
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data.strHtml}} />;
```

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` should almost always be avoided, there are better ways to do this (see the answer about `react-html-parser`).

Comment: alephtwo, how about performance with large HTML strings in react-html-parser?

Comment: Thank you but they've said it's dangerous. [https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)